# SuiteCRM developing a custom module

Tags: module, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I am trying to build a custom module based on the 'basic' template, with extra fields **without** using the module builder.

I have looked trough the SugarCRM 6.5 documentation, bought the book SuiteCRM for Developers and looked trough the sources of existing modules, but I still can not figure out how to put a working module together.

Does a minimal module template exists anywhere? What I am looking for is a fully working module with one extra field, which can be deployed on a SuiteCRM instance. I can take it from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no minimal module template that I know of, you may want to consider creating a test module through module builder and exporting that to see what the parts are.

Usually though modules have the following files. Example uses the module `ABC_Sport`.

> custom/Extension/application/Ext/Include/ABC_Sport.php

This adds the module to the module list and adds the beans. I.e.

```
$beanList['ABC_Sport'] = 'ABC_Sport';
$beanFiles['ABC_Sport'] = 'modules/ABC_Sport/ABC_Sport.php';
$moduleList[] = 'ABC_Sport';
```

> custom/Extension/application/Ext/Include/en_us.ABC_Sport.php

(Note you may want to add files for different languages).

Next up you'll need to create the bean file in

> modules/ABC_Sport/ABC_Sport.php

and the vardefs in

> modules/ABC_Sport/vardefs.php

I'm not totally sure if the metadata files are required or not but you'll also likely want to add the editviewdefs,detailviewdefs and listviewdefs.